# How do I get RTTI information on the IDE

Tags: delphi, hook, rtti, virtual-functions, toolsapi

I want to get the VMT entry for `TExceptionNotificationDlg` which resides in dbkdebugidexxx.bpl.
The IDE loads this module shortly after startup.
I want to prevent the exception report dialog from displaying and substitute my own display instead.

The easy way is to intercept this window's `ShowModal` function. 
ShowModal is a virtual function and it is thus stored in the VMT.
By default the VMT of this class contains a link to `CustomForm.ShowModal`, therefore simple hooking is out. I need to modify the VMT.
The IDE loads my code as a DLL on startup.

How do I get the address of the VMT if all I have is the `name` and `HModule` of the module (`dbkdebugidexxx.bpl`) and the name of the Window class (`TExceptionNotificationDlg`) ?

*Note that this Form only gets created when an exception gets displayed and is destroyed right after, using the `HWnd` to obtain info is out (I previously used the HWnd of a created form to access a form's published info https://compilerintrinsics.wordpress.com/, but I cannot do that here)*.

Comment: Maybe you could hook TForm.Create, check for the class there and patch it?

Comment: That might work, let me try that.